# Use of gpio interrupt 2 rather than interrupt 3

Tags: gpio, kernel, interrupts

I have studied in bcm2835 manual that its gpio peripheral can generate three interrupt lines.  But in the same manual (interrupts section) I found that there are four gpio interrupts, `gpio_int[0]` to `gpio_int[4]`.  The gpio irq used by the rpi is `gpio_int[3]`, which I found in `arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm2708_gpio.c` from the linux kernel source.

What happens if I replace that `gpio_int[3]` to `gpio_int[2]`?  Will I still be able to get interrupts if one of the gpios is set (similar to when `gpio_int[3]` is used)?

Comment: Seems this was true even for RPi1, based on comments in https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/00445b5d5866c7b31bcfc59e907c9062100b4b0a#diff-cf078559c38543ac72c5db99323e236d

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "gpio_int[0] to gpio_int[3]", right? Not "gpio_int[0] to gpio_int[4]". There is no gpio_int[4] mentioned in that manual.

The bcm2835 manual that you referenced was written for the first generation Raspberry Pi, in which there were only 2 banks of GPIO pins.

On the BCM2837 (the SoC used in the Raspberry Pi 3), there are actually 3 banks of GPIO pins, so there are four interrupt lines going from the GPIO controller to the interrupt controller.

- gpio_int[0] for BANK0 (pins 0-27)
- gpio_int[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxUF5.png) for BANK1 (pins 28-45)
- gpio_int[2] for BANK2 (pins 46-53)
- gpio_int[3] for all the pins

You can verify this on the Raspberry Pi 3 with the "raspi-gpio get" command, which lists each pin's function (INPUT/OUTPUT/ALT). If you filter the results with grep, you should see:

```
raspi-gpio get | grep BANK

BANK0 (GPIO 0 to 27):
BANK1 (GPIO 28 to 45):
BANK2 (GPIO 46 to 53):
```

Even though the GPIO controller in the original BCM2835 only had 2 banks, Broadcom was forward–looking and reserved a bit in each register of the interrupt controller for future versions, the gpio controller of which would have an additional bank.

If you are using a pi that has a gpio controller with 3 banks and you replace gpio_int[3] with gpio_int[2], you will only be able to get interrupts if one of the gpios in bank2 (pins 46-53) is set, but those pins are not exposed on the header and are connected to the SD card.

[image]